# How to create "lockscreen-like" music playback controls

Tags: android, button, android-intent, widget

I am trying to create widget that can control music playback. Basically the same as the widget that appears on lockscreen when music is playing. (Which as I read somewhere, is connected to the [Remote Control Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) - is that true?) My problem:
I was able to create Media Buttons using the following code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    synchronized (this) {
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
        sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
        sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
```

First, I thought this was the solution used also in the lockscreen widget. But then I noticed that this solution works only with some music players, but certainly not with all that can be controlled by default lockscreen widget(f.e. DoubleTwist responds to lockscreen widget, but not to my Media Buttons). So I spent last few days digging in the Android sources, Logcat outputs and various forums, but I was not able to find any difference between intents called by my buttons and by buttons on the lockscreen widget.

What exactly is lockscreen widget doing to control apps that are not listening to my Media Button intents?

Or, can somebody at least help me to find the source code of this widget? I tried default music app, audio service, remote control client, widgets, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working on my app I've actually found how to implement your own RemoteControlDisplay which can control music player the same way the lockscreen does.

Basically, you extend IRemoteControlDisplay$Stub, which sends messages to special handler, this handler updates metadata and thing. Then you register your own class extended from IRemoteControlDisplay$Stub by calling to AudioManager#registerRemoteControlDisplay().

And then you unregister it by calling AudioManager#unregisterRemoteControlDisplay().

It's fairly complex, but I've wrote an article on how to this.
I've published it on XDA, check it here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=44513199

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly is lockscreen widget doing to control apps that are not listening to my Media Button intents?

Based on the docs, it is doing what those apps asked it to do -- execute the `PendingIntent` supplied to it by the `RemoteControlClient`. Notably:

- it will not be an ordered broadcast, as `PendingIntent` does not support it
- it may be one targeted at the specific media client, via `setComponent()`
- it may or may not have the extras you are trying (incorrectly) to use

(The "incorrectly" part is because you are sending two `ACTION_UP` operations some of the time, as `sendOrderedBroadcast()` is asynchronous with respect to the calling thread, and therefore you may be replacing your `ACTION_DOWN` with `ACTION_UP` before the first ordered broadcast is sent. You are better off using a separate `Intent` object for each broadcast.)

However, while the docs claim that the `PendingIntent` needs to be set up for `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`, I would not be surprised if this is a documentation error, and that no specific action is needed, as `setComponent()` is sufficient to deliver the broadcast to the right receiver.

Comment: Thanks for correction, at first I was using two intents but then I found this solution somewhere, and because so far it was working fine, I decided to give it a try.